# Swift Problema na Multi Seleção UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uitableview

Tenho uma tableView que quando está no modo "Edit" eu posso selecionar cada item e tomar uma ação, por exemplo remover os itens selecionados.

Quando seleciono os itens, os primeiros ficam sem "Divisão de linha", e os debaixo ficam selecionados normalmente como mostra o print a seguir:

[image: Os três primeiros ficaram sem borda de divisão]

O que pode ser? Um bug do XCode ou há alguma implementação que corrija isso?

Quando eu faço o scroll para baixo os de cima somem também a borda de divisão da tableView.

Comment: Olá Leonardo, você poderia dar mais algumas informações como código da criação da tableView e da parte que você seleciona as células? Tive um problema parecido só que era só na primeira célula, quem sabe é o mesmo erro que eu estava cometendo. Obrigado :)

Answer (score 1):

Este problema ocorre no iOS 7 ou no iOS 8? Ou em ambos?

A `UITableView` no iOS utiliza um conceito de "reciclagem" das cédulas. Toda vez que você utiliza o *scroll* da *table view* ele recarrega as cédulas. Você pode resolver este problema de algumas maneiras diferentes.

**Se for a ocasião do iOS 7, você pode redefinir o estilo do separador da *table view***

Utilizando os métodos *delegate* da *table* você redefine o estilo das cédulas.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // Redefinindo o estilo do separador
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // Redefinindo o estilo do separador
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine;
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Redefinindo o estilo do separador
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // Por garantia também redefine o estilo do separador ao selecionar a cédula
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine;
 }
```

**Se você utiliza cédulas customizadas**

Você tem de registrar a cédula no `viewDidLoad`.

```
self.tableView.registerClass(CustomClassCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

**Solução mais drástica caso nenhuma destas funcione**

Você pode adicionar uma `UIView` de cor cinza com altura de `1` na parte inferior da cédula e remover o estilo do separador, definindo o estilo para `None`. Porém não seria a melhor prática.

**EDIT**

**Solução com cédulas carregadas a partir de um nib**

Para criar a cédula a partir de um Nib, no viewDidLoad você deve registrar o identificador da mesma:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CellNibName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}
```

No método `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomClassCell
     .
     .
     .
     return cell
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou, pois estou implementando na versão 8 do iOS e minha "Cédula" é registrada como UINib. Let xib = UINib(nibName: "MinhaCell", bundle: nil)

Comment: @LeonardoRocha no viewDidLoad registre seu nib `self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CellNibName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")`. Caso ainda não funcione dê mais detalhes sobre a criação da sua TableView e cédulas

Comment: @LeonardoRocha adicionei o trecho de código para  a criação e registro da Cell a partir de um Nib

Answer (score 0):

Nunca trabalhei com cédulas customizadas, porém vejamos o que tenho para tentar ajudar. Certifique que sua tableView apresenta atributos de separador de cédulas no default

[image: Atributos].

Certifique também o mesmo atributo na própria cédula

[image: cédula]

E por ultimo certifique se você não possui mais de uma cédula no tableView contendo atributos diferentes.

[image: Table View Cells]

Comment: Conferi e minha tableView e Cell. estão exatamante assim.

Comment: Porém o bug perssiste.

Comment: Você tem mais de uma cédula no próprio Table View?